# exclude resources using gradle 6.6

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, publishing

With Gralde 6.6 it is suggested to use the predefined function when publish a jar:

```
java {
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

I am using plugin `mave-publish`. How can I exclude the files in `resources` to be in the generated jar? I need to publish sources and resources as two different jar.

Comment: `withSourcesJar()` and `withJavadocJar()` add a `sourcesJar` and `javadocJar` task, respectively. I presume you can customize those tasks like the standard `jar` task.

Comment: I tried to add a customized `sourceJar` task but it claims that a sourceJar task already exists (`Cannot add task 'sourcesJar' as a task with that name already exists`).

Comment: You don't want to add or create the task, just customize it. At least with the Kotlin DSL using `tasks.named<Jar>("sourcesJar") { }` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding `tasks.sourcesJar { from sourceSets.main.allJava classifier = 'sources'}` it doesn't raise an error, but doesn't work, it just published the jar with all resources. maybe I am not doing it correctly

Comment: Try using `include` or `exclude`. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.html (note those methods come from `AbstractCopyTask`)